# How to make an index-agnostic 2-tuple?

Tags: python, tuples, memoization

I am implementing a function with 2 arguments and caching the result for performance ("Memoization" technique). But I see duplications in the caching function. For example:

```
@memoize
def fn(a,b):
    #do something.
```

The problem is that I know in advance that `fn(a,b) == fn(b,a)`, so I would like it to understand that the argument tuple `(a,b)` is equivalent to `(b,a)` in this case, but this function presently caches them as 2 separate entries.

Do I need to make a new class for that purpose or is there any other more elegant way? Although I know that I can cache the same function return value for both the tuples, but I would really want to know how to implement "index-agnostic" tuples.

This memoization code is just an example, I want my tuple object to be extremely general purpose which can be used in other situations also.

Comment: A simple solution is to use `sorted(argument_tuple)` or `frozenset(argument_tuple)` as the cache key.

Comment: Or `tuple(sorted(argument_tuple))`

Comment: Unless you want to make it very general, you could cache against `(a, b)` and `(b, a)` at the same time. So you call the function once when e.g. `fn(1, 2)` is invoked, at which time you also pre-cache in case `fn(2, 1)` ever gets invoked.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I would really like it to be extremaly general purpose, this memoization  is just an example off the top of my head.

Comment: Does the `@memoize` decoration allow you to specify how the cache key is computed?

Comment: @Barmar. I would rather only mess with the 2-tuple I am dealing with. I don't want to make any change in any other code. Just want to make this tuple general purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split it into two functions. The public function takes arguments in any order, and calls an internal function with the arguments sorted. The inner function is the one with the cache.

```
def fn(*args):
    return cached_fn(*sorted(args))

@memoize
def cached_fn(*args)
    # do something
```

This is a time-space tradeoff -- there some extra function calls in order to cut the size of the cache in half. Hopefully you don't have functions with really long argument lists, so the sorting should not add too much overhead.

This solution requires that the datatype of the arguments have a comparison function so they can be sorted. I can't think of a way to write this in a general way without such a prerequisite. When dealing with certain types you may be able to devise a custom method to canonicalize the order. Or you may be able to use your own hashing function in the cache, and make it order-agnostic.

Comment: thanks, but how can I make it general purpose, not specific to this case. like the one   answered by @blhsing but maybe a little simpler??

Comment: I've generalized the visible function

Comment: Do you mean `*sorted(args)`? Tuples don't have that method.

Comment: Had a feeling I might have gotten that backwards.

Comment: Keep in mind that this only works if the objects in the argument list are sortable/comparable, so is probably not as general-purpose as it could be, if that's what the OP is looking for. Also keep in mind that sorting has a higher cost in time complexity than counting, though it would not matter much unless the length of the argument list is long.

Comment: @blhsing You get my drift brother. That's exactly what I meant to ask.

Comment: @blhsing Good point, I've added some discussion of that requirement in the answer. I already addressed the performance impact of sorting.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an extremely general solution, for not just two parameters, but possibly multiple ones, where `(a, b, a)` is treated the same as `(a, a, b)` but differently from `(a, b, b)`, you can use `frozenset(Counter(argument_tuple).items())` to count the number of occurrences of each value and turn the resulting dict into a frozenset of tuples (after `from collections import Counter`).